# UITableView with different row heights for different sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using custom cells for different sections within my tableview. I know that I can adjust the height of the roows of my table in Interface Builder.
but how do I control the height of my tableview's rows if I have 3 sections each with a different row height?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks. Im new to this so Ive been trying to figure all this out. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Implement [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your `UITableViewDelegate` (which is most likely your table-view's controller).

Answer (score 4):

In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method set the section with this `indexPath.section`. It set the section index where you want to set different row height for a particular cell compare to others. And inside it set the `indexPath.row` It set the row index where you actually set the different height.

In the below example I set `80.0f` height for the 1st cell of my 4th section. And others set as `50.0f`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            return 80;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 50;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the height of the cells in other sections, then use "return UITableView.automaticDimension" instead of "return 0".  And remove the else condition of "return 50" also